# Duplicate class issue when adding a new dependency on flutter :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses

Tags: android, flutter

I received this error after I added the in_app_review dependency to my project

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.common.IntentSenderForResultStarter found in modules jetified-core-1.9.1-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.9.1) and jetified-core-common-2.0.2-runtime (com.google.android.play:core-common:2.0.2)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.common.LocalTestingException found in modules jetified-core-1.9.1-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.9.1) and jetified-core-common-2.0.2-runtime (com.google.android.play:core-common:2.0.2)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.common.PlayCoreDialogWrapperActivity found in modules jetified-core-1.9.1-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.9.1) and jetified-core-common-2.0.2-runtime (com.google.android.play:core-common:2.0.2)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.listener.StateUpdatedListener found in modules jetified-core-1.9.1-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.9.1) and jetified-core-common-2.0.2-runtime (com.google.android.play:core-common:2.0.2)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.review.ReviewInfo found in modules jetified-core-1.9.1-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.9.1) and jetified-review-2.0.1-runtime (com.google.android.play:review:2.0.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.review.ReviewManager found in modules jetified-core-1.9.1-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.9.1) and jetified-review-2.0.1-runtime (com.google.android.play:review:2.0.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.review.ReviewManagerFactory found in modules jetified-core-1.9.1-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.9.1) and jetified-review-2.0.1-runtime (com.google.android.play:review:2.0.1)
     Duplicate class com.google.android.play.core.review.testing.FakeReviewManager found in modules jetified-core-1.9.1-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.9.1) and jetified-review-2.0.1-runtime (com.google.android.play:review:2.0.1)

     Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

This is a list of dependencies that I use,

```
dependencies:
  adhan: ^2.0.0-nullsafety.2
  # agora_uikit: ^1.0.2
  archive: ^3.2.2
  assets_audio_player: ^3.0.3+6
  audio_service: ^0.18.7
  audio_session: ^0.1.6+1
  audioplayers: ^5.2.0
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.3
  #cached_video_player: ^2.0.4
  camera: ^0.10.0
  carousel_slider: ^4.1.1
  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.6
  country_picker: ^2.0.22
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  dio: ^5.1.1
  easy_localization: ^3.0.0
  extended_image: ^8.1.1
  external_path: ^1.0.1
  file_picker: ^5.2.4
  file_saver: ^0.1.0
  firebase_auth: ^4.14.1
  firebase_core: ^2.4.0
  firebase_storage: ^11.0.8
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_compass:
#    git: https://github.com/hemanthrajv/flutter_compass.git
  flutter_downloader:  ^1.11.3
  flutter_facebook_auth: ^5.0.8
  flutter_timezone: ^1.0.6
  # flutter_neumorphic: ^3.2.0
  flutter_painter_v2: ^2.0.1
  flutter_reaction_button: ^2.0.1+2
  flutter_share: ^2.0.0
  flutter_sound: ^9.2.13
  flutter_svg: ^1.0.3
  flutter_swipe_action_cell: ^3.0.7
  fluttertoast: ^8.0.8
  gallery_saver: ^2.3.2
  geocoding: ^2.0.4
  geolocator: ^9.0.1
  google_mobile_ads: ^2.0.1
  google_sign_in: ^5.2.3
  hijri: ^3.0.0
  hijri_picker: ^3.0.0
  http: ^1.1.0
  image_editor: ^1.0.2
  image_picker: ^1.0.4
  in_app_purchase: ^3.1.11
  intl: ^0.18.0
  path: ^1.8.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.9
  percent_indicator: ^4.2.2
  permission_handler: ^10.0.0
  phosphor_flutter: ^1.4.0
  photo_gallery:
  provider: ^6.0.2
  scrollable_positioned_list: ^0.3.4
  share_plus: ^6.3.4
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.13
  sliding_up_panel: ^2.0.0
  sqflite: ^2.0.2
  story_view: ^0.16.0
  table_calendar: ^3.0.5
  the_apple_sign_in: ^1.1.1
  transparent_image: ^2.0.0
  url_launcher: ^6.1.0
  uuid: ^3.0.6
  video_player: ^2.5.3
  visibility_detector: ^0.3.3
  chewie: ^1.5.0
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.2.0
  flutter_dotenv: ^5.0.2
  geocoder_buddy: ^1.0.1
  maps_launcher: ^2.2.0
  youtube_player_iframe: ^3.1.0
  qr_code_scanner: ^1.0.1
  scan: ^1.6.0
  qr_flutter: ^4.1.0
  flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.1
  clipboard: ^0.1.3
  flutter_colorpicker: ^1.0.3
  modal_bottom_sheet: ^3.0.0-pre
  smooth_page_indicator: ^1.0.0+2
  google_fonts: ^4.0.3
  geoflutterfire: ^3.0.3
  just_audio: ^0.9.29
  firebase_messaging: ^14.1.4
  cloud_functions: ^4.0.6
  flutter_local_notifications: ^15.1.0
  workmanager: ^0.5.2
  timezone: ^0.9.0
  rxdart: ^0.27.7
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.3.0
  dotted_border: ^2.0.0+3
  video_thumbnail: ^0.5.3
  amplify_flutter: ^0.5.1
  amplify_storage_s3: ^0.5.1
  amplify_auth_cognito: ^0.5.1
  video_trimmer: ^2.0.1
  emoji_picker_flutter: ^1.6.1
  draggable_bottom_sheet: ^1.0.2
  language_picker: ^0.4.3
  shimmer: ^2.0.0
  firebase_ui_firestore: ^1.3.2
  infinite_scroll_pagination: ^3.2.0
  grouped_list: ^5.1.2
  flutter_wall_layout: ^2.1.1
  flag: ^6.0.0
#  stack_appodeal_flutter: ^3.0.2
  firebase_performance: ^0.9.2+1
  firebase_crashlytics: ^3.3.4
  aws_s3_upload: ^1.5.0
  vibration: ^1.7.7
  sliver_tools: ^0.2.12
  image_editor_plus: ^1.0.3
  store_redirect: ^2.0.1
  in_app_review: 2.0.8
  # launch_review: ^3.0.1
  # advanced_in_app_review: ^1.2.1
```

Kindly help me guys. Thanks. I dont know what to do.

I tried to exclude one of the java classes on the `android/app/build.gradle` but it didnt work out or I mightve wrote it wrongly. Please help me. Thanks a lot!